# El valor del input no funciona

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un programa para calcular la cantidad de personas atendidas a lo largo de una semana, mi funcion para calcular esto, funciona bien, el problema es que los valores de mis inputs llegan mal a la hora de ser calculados. parece que no reconoce bien el valor real que se pone en los inputs y me da porcentajes finales absurdos

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Promedio de pacientes</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Promedio de pacientes semanales, Jornada de Cirugia</h1>
    <form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Dia</th>
                <th>Agendado</th>
                <th>Atendido</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Lunes</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="x1" type="number"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="y1" type="number"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Martes</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="x2" type="number"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="y2" type="number"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Miercoles</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="x3" type="number"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="y3" type="number"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Jueves</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="x4" type="number"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="y4" type="number"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Viernes</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="x5" type="number"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="y5" type="number"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <button type="button" onclick="OnclickPromedio()">Calcular Promedio</button>
        <p id="resultado"></p>
    </form>
    <script src="./promedioClinica.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Esta es la parte de javascript y creo que aqui es donde esta el error

```
function OnclickPromedio(){
    const x1 = document.getElementById("x1").value;
    // const x1Val = x1.value;
    const y1 = document.getElementById("y1").value;
    // const y1Val = y1.value;

    const x2 = document.getElementById("x2").value;
    // const x2Val = x2.value;
    const y2 = document.getElementById("y2").value;
    // const y2Val = y2.value;

    const x3 = document.getElementById("x3").value;
    // const x3Val = x3.value;
    const y3 = document.getElementById("y3").value;
    // const y3Val = y3.value;

    const x4 = document.getElementById("x4").value;
    // const x4Val = x4.value;
    const y4 = document.getElementById("y4").value;
    // const y4Val = y4.value;

    const x5 = document.getElementById("x5").value;
    // const x5Val = x5.value;
    const y5 = document.getElementById("y5").value;
    // const y5Val = y5.value;

    const promedioPacientes = CalcularPromedioClinica(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,y1,y2,y3,y4,y5);
    const Resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
    Resultado.innerText = "El promedio de pacientes que fueron atendidos esta semana es del: " + promedioPacientes + "%";
}

function CalcularPromedioClinica(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,y1,y2,y3,y4,y5){
    const pacientesAgendados = parseInt(x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5);
    const pacientesAtendidos = parseInt(y1 + y2 + y3 + y4 + y5);

    const promedio = pacientesAtendidos/pacientesAgendados * 100;

    return promedio;
}
```

les agradeceria mucho que me ayudaran, porque de verdad que llevo horas intentando e investigando y no consigo como resolverlo por mi cuenta

Comment: Yo acabo de probar (https://jsfiddle.net/2xjp7o5c/) y funciona correctamente. Otra cosa es que cuando hay muchos decimales no lo restringes a dos (o a un entero), o problemas como comprobar que no haya división por 0 (deberías comprobar que `pacientesAgendados!=0` antes de la división). Pero por el resto, funciona bien

Comment: No encuentro fallas en el cálculo, pongo 4 agendados cada día y 1 atendido cada día y me da como resultado: 'El promedio de pacientes que fueron atendidos esta semana es del: 25%' Cosa que es correcta. Que error te está dando? podrías mostrarnos el error?

Comment: "El valor del input no funciona". Falso. El elemento `input` (y su valor) funciona correctamente desde 1995, cuando HTML fue actualizada a la versión 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas transformar a un entero no es el resultado de la suma de cada input, si no el "value" de cada input. Si no lo haces así es cuando vas a tener problemas, ya que el "value" de los input es de tipo `string` siempre y se van a concatenar en vez de a sumar.

```js
function OnclickPromedio(){
    const x1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("x1").value);
    // const x1Val = x1.value;
    const y1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("y1").value);
    // const y1Val = y1.value;

    const x2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("x2").value);
    // const x2Val = x2.value;
    const y2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("y2").value);
    // const y2Val = y2.value;

    const x3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("x3").value);
    // const x3Val = x3.value;
    const y3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("y3").value);
    // const y3Val = y3.value;

    const x4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("x4").value);
    // const x4Val = x4.value;
    const y4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("y4").value);
    // const y4Val = y4.value;

    const x5 = parseInt(document.getElementById("x5").value);
    // const x5Val = x5.value;
    const y5 = parseInt(document.getElementById("y5").value);
    // const y5Val = y5.value;

    const promedioPacientes = CalcularPromedioClinica(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,y1,y2,y3,y4,y5);
    const Resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
    Resultado.innerText = "El promedio de pacientes que fueron atendidos esta semana es del: " + promedioPacientes + "%";
}

function CalcularPromedioClinica(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,y1,y2,y3,y4,y5){
    const pacientesAgendados = x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5;
    const pacientesAtendidos = y1 + y2 + y3 + y4 + y5;

    const promedio = pacientesAtendidos/pacientesAgendados * 100;

    return promedio;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>Promedio de pacientes</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Promedio de pacientes semanales, Jornada de Cirugia</h1>
    <form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Dia</th>
                <th>Agendado</th>
                <th>Atendido</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Lunes</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="x1" type="number"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="y1" type="number"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Martes</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="x2" type="number"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="y2" type="number"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Miercoles</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="x3" type="number"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="y3" type="number"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Jueves</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="x4" type="number"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="y4" type="number"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Viernes</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="x5" type="number"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="y5" type="number"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <button type="button" onclick="OnclickPromedio()">Calcular Promedio</button>
        <p id="resultado"></p>
    </form>
    <script src="./promedioClinica.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, era eso, es mi primera vez con javascript

Comment: Date cuenta que el operador +, en Javascript sirve tanto para concatenar `string` como para sumar `number`. Así que hay que tener mucho cuidado con el tipo de los datos con los que operamos.